# Как разделить текст на N частей?

Tags: delphi

Как сделать что бы если количество строк не кратно количеству частей то последний файл делался меньше? То есть пусть все первые файлы равны, последний меньше.

Есть код делит файл на части, но в данном случае делит не правильно:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  //Количество частей на которые надо разбить файл.
  N = 10;
var
  F1, F2 : File;
  i, SizePart, SizePartAdd : Cardinal;
  Buff : array of Byte;
begin
  ..
  AssignFile(F1, OpenDialog1.FileName);
  Reset(F1, 1);

  SizePart := FileSize(F1) div N;
  SizePartAdd := FileSize(F1) mod N;

  SetLength(Buff, SizePart);

  for i := 1 to N do begin
    AssignFile(F2, OpenDialog1.FileName + '.part' + IntToStr(i));
    Rewrite(F2, 1);
    BlockRead(F1, Pointer(Buff)^, SizePart);
    BlockWrite(F2, Pointer(Buff)^, SizePart);
    if (i = N) and (SizePartAdd > 0) then begin
      BlockRead(F1, Pointer(Buff)^, SizePartAdd);
      BlockWrite(F2, Pointer(Buff)^, SizePartAdd);
    end;
    CloseFile(F2);
  end;

  CloseFile(F1);
end;
```

Comment: а как делит в данном случае? а как на примере с числами надо разделить? число каких строк там кратно, если файл бинарный? Если текстовый, то каких потенциальных размеров, и зачем все это старые методы работы с файлами?

Comment: В данном случае делит на равные файлы со смещением строки. И некоторые строки смещаются и получается некрасиво. Если сделать что все первые файлы равны, а самый последний меньше то было бы отлично. А текстовый файл 500 мегабайт и больше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разбитие текстового файла на N частей, в первых N - 1 частях - равное количество строк:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
F1, F2: TextFile;
SizeFile, SizePart, SizePartLast, i, j, N: cardinal;
TempStr: string;
begin
if OpenDialog1.InitialDir = '' then begin
    OpenDialog1.InitialDir := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName);
  end;
  if not OpenDialog1.Execute then Exit;
  AssignFile(F1,OpenDialog1.FileName);
  Reset(F1);
  SizeFile := 0;
  //подсчитаем количество строк
  while not eof(F1) do
  begin
  readln(F1,tempstr);
  inc(SizeFile);
  end;
//вернемся в начало файла
Reset(F1);
//разобьем файл на заданное количество частей
N := 10;
  SizePart := SizeFile div N;
  SizePartLast := SizePart;
  if SizeFile mod N > 0 then
  begin
  SizePart := SizePart + 1;
  SizePartLast := SizeFile - SizePart * (N - 1);
  end;
  for i := 1 to N - 1 do
  begin
    AssignFile(F2, OpenDialog1.FileName + '.part' + IntToStr(i));
    Rewrite(F2);
    for j := 1 to SizePart do
    begin
    readln(F1,TempStr);
    writeln(F2,TempStr);
    end;
    CloseFile(F2);
  end;
//обработка последнего куска
  AssignFile(F2, OpenDialog1.FileName + '.part' + IntToStr(N));
  Rewrite(F2);
  for j := 1 to SizePart do
  begin
    readln(F1,TempStr);
    writeln(F2,TempStr);
    end;
  CloseFile(F2);
  CloseFile(F1);
end;
```

Попробовал на файлике 60 мегабайт - разбило на 10 частей меньше, чем за 10 секунд. Если подсчет строк в файле выполнять не так топорно, как я (считывая по очереди все строки и увеличивая счетчик), а как-нибудь более красиво - будет работать быстрее. Итоговые размеры частей не будут совпадать, ведь количество символов во всех строчках разное. Первый вариант ответа оставил на тот случай, если кто-нибудь когда-нибудь будет искать информацию о том, как разбить произвольный файл на куски равного размера.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что нужно делать так: хотим побить текстовый файл на N кусков, проверяем количество записей в исходном файле на кратность N. Если количество записей кратно - бьем на равные части, если не кратно, то к размеру части (FileSize(F1)  div N) добавляем 1 запись. Соответственно, размер первых N - 1 кусков будет равен FileSize(F1)  div N + 1, размер последнего куска: FileSize(F1) - (FileSize(F1) div N + 1) * (N - 1). Это гарантированно будет работать, если FileSize(F1) div N > N. Ну и реализация на Delphi:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  //Количество частей на которые надо разбить файл.
  N = 10;
var
  F1, F2 : File;
  i, SizeFile, SizePart, SizePartLast : Cardinal;
  Buff : array of Byte;
begin
  if OpenDialog1.InitialDir = '' then begin
    OpenDialog1.InitialDir := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName);
  end;
  if not OpenDialog1.Execute then Exit;
  if not FileExists(OpenDialog1.FileName) then begin
    ShowMessage('Указанный файл не найден. Действие отменено.');
    Exit;
  end;

  AssignFile(F1, OpenDialog1.FileName);
  Reset(F1, 1);

  SizeFile :=  FileSize(F1);
  SizePart := SizeFile div N;
  SizePartLast := SizePart;
  if SizePart < N then begin
    ShowMessage('Указанный файл слишком мал. Разбиение отменено.');
    CloseFile(F1);
    Exit;
  end;

  if SizeFile mod N > 0 then
  begin
  SizePart := SizePart + 1;
  SizePartLast := SizeFile - SizePart * (N - 1);
  end;
  SetLength(Buff, SizePart);
  for i := 1 to N - 1 do
  begin
    AssignFile(F2, OpenDialog1.FileName + '.part' + IntToStr(i));
    Rewrite(F2, 1);
    BlockRead(F1, Pointer(Buff)^, SizePart);
    BlockWrite(F2, Pointer(Buff)^, SizePart);
    CloseFile(F2);
  end;
//обработка последнего куска
  AssignFile(F2, OpenDialog1.FileName + '.part' + IntToStr(N));
  Rewrite(F2, 1);
  SetLength(Buff, SizePartLast);
  BlockRead(F1, Pointer(Buff)^, SizePartLast);
  BlockWrite(F2, Pointer(Buff)^, SizePartLast);
  CloseFile(F2);
  CloseFile(F1);
end;
```

P.S. С функцией FileSize я раньше не работал никогда, почитал описание - она возвращает размер в ЗАПИСЯХ, по умолчанию размер записи - 128 байт. Т.е. красиво построчно эта процедура все равно не побьет, надо тогда пользоваться функциями для работы с текстовыми файлами.

Comment: Может подскажете аналогичную функцию как быстро разбить файлы размером от 700 мегабайт. То есть пусть все первые файлы равны, последний меньше.